# match line that doesnt contain certain words

Tags: sql, regex, database, postgresql, match

I have the following string:

```
ignoreword1,word1, ignoreword2
```

i would like to match any word that is not `ignoreword1` or `ignoreword2`

this is what i have so far

```
(?s)^((?!ignoreword1).)*$
```

the main goal is to use the regex as part of postgresql database to select rows where the column match a substring after removing "ignoreword1", "ignoreword2" and the comma ","

Comment: *to match any word that is not ignoreword1 or ignoreword2* use `\b(?!(?:ignoreword1|ignoreword1)\b)\w+`, but perhaps, you mean to match a *string*, then, try `^(?!(?:ignoreword1|ignoreword1)$).*`

Comment: please post it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match any word that is not `ignoreword1` or `Ignoreword2` use

```
\b(?!(?:ignoreword1|ignoreword2)\b)\w+
```

In PostgreSQL, word boundaries are `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`, so use something like:

```
[[:<:]](?!(?:ignoreword1|ignoreword2)[[:>:]])[a-zA-Z]+
```

Pattern details:

- `[[:<:]]` - leading word boundary
- `(?!(?:ignoreword1|ignoreword2)[[:>:]])` - fail the match if the whole string is either `ignoreword1` or `ignoreword2`
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more any ASCII letters.

Comment: SELECT SUBSTRING(columnName FROM '\b(?!(?:ignoreword1|ignoreword1)\b)\w+') as sub_t, *
FROM   TableT .. sub_t should contain the matching word in each column. in my case it is empty. it works on regex101.com

Comment: It does not seem PostgreSQL regex supports lookarounds at all. However, try `[[:<:]](?!(?:ignoreword1|ignoreword2)[[:>:]])[a-zA-Z]+`

Comment: this worked. thanks a lot! i bet many people are wondering the same thing

Comment: Great! The documentation is full of confusing stuff, so your feedback is really very useful.